We need to move the subchart to the top using billboard.js
Can anyone find the solution of the problem that I want to move the chart to top then mainchart in browser.Please let us know how to resolve this
I want to move the subchart at the top then mainchart should display in browser.
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
    ["sample", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
    ],
    type: "line", // for ESM specify as: line()
  },
  subchart: {
    show: true, // for ESM specify as: subchart()
    showHandle: true
  },
  bindto: "#subChart"
});


We don't know what 'move the subchart at the top then main chart should display in browser' means.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

whenever  run the above code, subchart appears below the mainchart, its there a way that subchart appear first then mainchart follow in browser?

This is a workaround you can use by leveraging the onbeforeinit hook in Billboard.js:
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [["sample", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]],
    type: "line", // for ESM specify as: line()
  },
  subchart: {
    show: true, // for ESM specify as: subchart()
    showHandle: true,
  },
  bindto: "#subChart",
  **onbeforeinit: function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const svg = document.querySelector("#subChart svg");
      const subchartGroup = svg.querySelector(".bb-subchart");
      const mainGroup = svg.querySelector(".bb-main");
      if (subchartGroup && mainGroup) {
        const subchartTransform = subchartGroup.getAttribute("transform");
        const mainChartTransform = mainGroup.getAttribute("transform");
        // Swap the transforms of the subchart and main chart
        mainGroup.setAttribute("transform", `${subchartTransform}`);
        subchartGroup.setAttribute("transform", `${mainChartTransform}`);
      }
    }, 0);
  },**
});

Explanation:

The onbeforeinit function is used to execute code before the chart is
fully initialized.
The setTimeout ensures the DOM is fully ready before attempting to
access and manipulate the SVG elements.
The code swaps the transform attributes of the main chart and the
subchart, effectively switching their positions.

